# Is pythonw exe an "external" application

Tags: python, external

Using Python 3.10:

```
import os
os.system('notepad.exe')
```

Notepad launches, but if I try that with pythonw.exe Idle doesn't launch but the exit code is also 0.
Not sure why. Is it because pythonw is not an external application? How can I launch IDLE from the interpreter?

I apologize, not sure how to include code properly....

Many thanks

Comment: `pythonw` doesn't do anything if called without arguments. So what do you expect?

Comment: If I put your code into `x.pyw` and run `pythonw x.pyw`, Notepad comes up just fine.  It does bring up another command window, because that's how `os.system` works.  How is IDLE involved?

Answer (score 1):

`pythonw` is not IDLE.  `pythonw` is just another copy of `python` that is marked as a Windows GUI application, so it doesn't attach to your terminal session.  IDLE is a separate command. Depending on where your Python installation is, you can run:

```
C:\Python310\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
```

Or, even easier:

```
pythonw -m idlelib
```

Comment: Hi, and thank for your various answers. The reason I was wondering about pythonw is because when I follow the shortcut trail  for IDLE on Win 10, it ends with pythonw.exe. From the other comments I was able to figure out the that python is a non-display version of the python interpreter that opens for only as long as is necessary to run a command. It is not clear to me how IDLE becomes associated with the request to pythonw just by looking at the shortcut trail. If you have any comments on that I would appreciate it. Thanks all for your help.